# Convert String type to Class type

Tags: angular, typescript

In Java we use something like this:

```java
Class<?> classType = Class.forName(className);
```

How can we achieve the same goal with Angular?

Comment: How can we achieve the same goal with TypeScript?* Angular is just a framework.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav oh yeah you're right my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's just object , you can convert like this

```
let a = 'object string';let jsObj = JSON.parse(a);console.log(jsObj);
```

Comment: no this is not my case, I just want the class type !